# Rigify doesn't move my mesh when constrained

Tags: rigging, constraints, rigify

I followed a Rigify tutorial to a T (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S52A-K5tLDc) but at around 8:40 when he constraints both of them mine just won't move and I have no idea why, I did the exact same with a previous model a month ago and it worked fine.

I also noticed the legs bend the wrong way but that's a headache for another time.

[.blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oWs65CtbnqKNaJTgaPSyKkHBb0DlSycN/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: Two problems: 1. You have around 11800 duplicate vertices on your model, and 2. That tutorial is done in Blender version 3 and you're using version 4 which uses Bone Collections instead of Layers! For 1, select your model, go into Edit mode, select All and then hit M > Merge by distance. For the second problem I'd suggest following CG Dive's [rigging tutorial](https://youtu.be/dDNUjGgCNys) using Blender 4. You can keep the armature you've already set up but follow his tutorial for the rest.

Comment: For the leg bending problem, in side view (3 on the numpad) move the armature knee joint forward and the heel joint back so that they aren't in line. That should stop the knee bending in the wrong direction.

Comment: @JohnEason I followed CG Dive's tutorial to a T but the same still happens, everything works totally fine until the automatic weight constraints which don't move the mesh around